# ServiceStack RequestLogs suddenly start returning 401 invalid role

Tags: servicestack

I am using the requestlogs plugin for some time now. However, suddenly I am getting a 401 response from all my services that use the plugin. The services run fine otherwise. Only, when trying to look at the logs, I get the 401.
I can see that the actual logging results are indeed fetched (GET ssr-results?id=..). Only the GET ../RequestLogs immediately terminate with a 401?

I have the most basic setup, only anonymous access enabled on IIS and I instantiate the plugin completely as is with defaults. The code is entirely boring. Only, it worked, until now.

EDIT: The answer as stated below is setting the RequiredRoles to null. I had read this, only, I didn't understand why it worked in the first place. But first I build in Debug mode, it started failing building in Release mode. That confused me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [RequestLogs feature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-logger) by default requires the `Admin` role unless ServiceStack is in [DebugMode](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Debugging#debugmode).

It can be enabled for all users with:

```
Plugins.Add(new RequestLogsFeature { 
    RequiredRoles = null
});
```